# How to calculate the response time of all the internal services being called in a controller class using AOP

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop, splunk

My Rest Api is developed in Spring Boot and for logging we are using Splunk and Spring AOP .My question is how to calculate the response time of all the internal services being  called. For now, I am able to get the end to end response time.
We need this for creating dashboard in Splunk to track the performance of Api.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn how to ask questions by understanding what an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and consequently provide code + more details by editing your question. Otherwise people will just guess what you might want and the answers will not be helpful to you. Nobody can know how to identify an "internal service" in your code base via aspect pointcut if you do not share details about package name scheme, class names, method names, annotations or similar structural characteristics which could be intercepted by an aspect.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example using @Around annotation of AspectJ.

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class MethodExecutionCalculationAspect {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Around("@annotation(com.in28minutes.springboot.tutorial.basics.example.aop.TrackTime)")
    public void around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        joinPoint.proceed();

        long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        logger.info("Time Taken by {} is {}", joinPoint, timeTaken);
    }
}
```

So, i think this is what you want to do.